# React Native unable to resolve module for static image

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I want to send images from one page to another with react native navigations

here are my codes

this is app.js file which is the main file to initialized  react navigations and pages

**App.js**

```
    import React from "react"
import Walkthrought1 from "./Pages/Walkthrought1/Walkthrought1.js"
import Walkthrought2 from "./Pages/Walkthrought2/Walkthrought2.js"

import {createAppContainer} from "react-navigation"
import {createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation-stack"

const PushRouteOne = createStackNavigator({
  Page1: {
    screen: Walkthrought1,
 },
 Page2: {
 screen:Walkthrought2,
 },
 /*
 Page3:{
 screen:Walkthrough03,
 },
 Login:  {
 screen:Register,
   }*/
 }, 
 {
  initialRouteName: "Page1",
  mode: "modal",
  headerMode: "none",
  })
  

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(PushRouteOne)

  export default class App extends React.Component {
  
    render() {
    return <AppContainer/>
    }
  }
```

And the another pages Walkthrought1 which is the list of images and select the image and send it to walkthrought2

**Walkthrought1.js**

```
      const products = [
      {
        id:'1',
      title:'Product1',
      image: require("./assest/image1.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id:'2',
    title:'Product2',
    image:require("./assest/image2.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id:'3',
    title:'Product3',
    image:require("./assest/image3.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id:'4',
    title:'Product4',
    image:require("./assest/image4.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id:'5',
        title:'Product5',
        image:require("./assest/image5.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id:'6',
    title:'Product6',
    image:require("./assest/image7.jpg"),
      },
  
      {
        id:'7',
    title:'Product7',
    image:require("./assest/image8.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id:'8',
    title:'Product8',
   image: require("./assest/image9.jpg"),
      },
  ];

  function Item({ id,title,image,selected,onSelect }) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        navigate("Page2",{
          Send_Image:image,
          Send_Title:title,
        });
        }}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    <Image style={styles.images} source={image}/>
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  
  

  export default class Walkthrought1 extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params ={} } = navigation.state
    }
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
    }


    render(){
  
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
          data={products}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
          <Item 
          title={item.title}
          image={item.image}
          /> }
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          extraData={selected}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
    }
  }
```

and this is Walkthrought2.js this page  showing image which is come from walkthrought1 with navigation

Walkthrought2.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

import {
    //responsiveheight,
    responsiveWidth,
    responsiveFontSize,
    responsiveHeight,
    } from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
    export default class Walkthrought2 extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params ={} } = navigation.state
    }
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const Get_Image = (this.props.navigation.params("Send_Image"));
        const Get_Title = (this.props.navigation.params("Send_Title"));
    }

render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>{<View>
      <Image style={styles.images} source={require(Get_Image)}/>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{Get_Title}</Text>

  </View>}</NavigationContainer>
    );
        
    
}
}
```

And when I ran i've given this error

[image]

Comment: Hi,  you need to import image component from react-native like on top
`import {Image} from 'react-native';`

Comment: Yes I wrote that

Comment: and you sure that your project is running in terminal? with npm start ?